# Конструкторы в классах C#

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь построить иерархию классов(из Main вызывается базовый конструктор,который в зависимости от некоторых параметров вызывает один из трех подклассов.)
Компилятор выдает ошибку " "***" не содержит конструктор,который принимает аргументы  " и "имена членов не могут совпадать с именами типов,в которых они содержаться". Как можно это исправить?

Вызов базового класса

```
var Price=new Edition(EditionType, PagesNumber, PrintType);
```

Сам базовый класс

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PriceCalculator
{
    public class Edition
    {
        private readonly int EditionType;
        private readonly int PagesNumber;
        private readonly int PrintType;
        public Edition(int EditionType, int PagesNumber, int PrintType)
        {

            this.EditionType = EditionType;
            this.PagesNumber = PagesNumber;
            this.PrintType = PrintType;
            int ApproxPrice = PagesNumber * PrintType;

            Calculate(ApproxPrice);


        }

        public int Calculate (int Price)
        {

            if (EditionType == 1)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(new Journal(Price));
                return value;
            }

            else { return 0; }




        }
    }
}
```

Класс Journal

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PriceCalculator

{
   public class Journal : Edition
    {
        private readonly int ApproxPrice;

        public Journal(int ApproxPrice)
        {
            this.ApproxPrice = ApproxPrice;
            ControlPrice(ApproxPrice);
        }

        public int ControlPrice(int Price)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            var mult = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            return Convert.ToInt32(ApproxPrice * mult);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что это такое? `public int Journal(int ApproxPrice)` вы пытаетесь в конструкторе вернуть значение?

Comment: конструктор возвращает объект класса, в данном случае в качестве конструктора идет попытка вызвать метод.

Answer (score 3):

Конструктор не может что-то возвращать.

```
public /*int*/ Edition(int EditionType, int PagesNumber, int PrintType)
{
  this.EditionType = EditionType;
  this.PagesNumber = PagesNumber;
  this.PrintType = PrintType;
  ApproxPrice = PagesNumber * PrintType;
}
```

---

> Я поменял код,но осталась одна ошибка в классе Journal "Отсутствует
>   аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру
>   "EditionType" из "Edition.Edition(int, int, int)"

У родительского класса `Edition` нет конструктора без параметров, вызов которого компилятор пытается вставить в Ваш код. Вот он и жалуется на отсутствие первого параметра `EditionType` в этом вызове.

```
    public Journal(int ApproxPrice) : base(?, ?, ?)
    {
        this.ApproxPrice = ApproxPrice;
        ControlPrice(ApproxPrice);
    }
```

Comment: еще `public int Journal(int ApproxPrice)`.

Comment: @LLENN Естественно.

Comment: @Igor,Я поменял код,но осталась одна ошибка в классе Journal "Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующий требуемому формальному параметру "EditionType" из "Edition.Edition(int, int, int)". Код в вопросе поменял

Comment: Кстати,я правильно реализовал возврат значений через другие функции?

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Очень неловко спрашивать у Вас  снова,но теперь выдает ошибку "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Edition.PrintType" требуется ссылка на объект ".  Что это за ссылка?

Comment: @Alexey Вы пытаетесь обратиться к `PrintType` используя тип `Edition`. А нужно использовать экземпляр класса - объект типа `Edition`.

Comment: @Igor У меня такая проблема со всеми тремя параметрами. Если я Вас правильно понял,нужно обращаться к переменным,обьявленным в Edition. Но они ведь и обьявлены там при помощи this.***=***?

Comment: @Alexey Покажите Ваш код, в котором есть `Edition.PrintType`.

Comment: @Igor public Journal(int ApproxPrice) : base (Edition.EditionType,Edition.PagesNumber,Edition.PrintType)

Comment: @Alexey Перечитайте мой комментарий выше. Не торопитесь. Подумайте.

Comment: @Igor Честно,думаю,но ничего в голову не приходит. Запутался окончательно. Фактически это мой второй код на шарпе,так что получается туго. Извините за такое количество вопросов. P.S. Пробовал обьявить Edition.PrintType - не вышло

Comment: @Alexey В этом вызове `base (Edition.EditionType,Edition.PagesNumber,Edition.PrintType)` Вы пытаетесь взять значения от типа, как если бы они были статическими полями/свойствами. Но это поля объекта типа `Edition`, который Вы здесь не создали. Что, собственно, Вы хотите передать в родительский конструктор?

Comment: @Igor Обратно в Edition хочу передать ApproxPrice(которую получаю из самого Edition) умноженную на значение,введенное пользователем в консоль

Comment: @Igor А эти значения возможно передать каким-то другим способом?

Comment: @Alexey Если `ApproxPrice` вычисляетеся, зачем Вы ее передаете в конструктор класса `Journal`? Напишите пока: `public Journal(int ApproxPrice) : base (5, 6, 7)`.

Comment: @Igor Потому что пытаюсь построить иерархию классов,если Вы об этом. С вариантом base (5, 6, 7) все работает,большое спасибо. Получается в моем случае, эти значения ни на что не влияют?

Comment: @Alexey Влияют. Но откуда эти значения должны браться, известно только Вам.