# Как передать несколько массивов в другие формы?

Tags: c#

В проекте есть 4 формы - первая просто вызывает остальные 3 , во второй вносятся данные,которые сохраняются в массивах(3 типа string и один типа int). Есть необходимость передать полученные данные в оставшиеся 2 формы. До этого я делал только формы,принимающие по одному значению каждого типа,и для передачи в остальные формы использовал отдельный static класс. В случае с массивами так сделать не получается. Что можно сделать для передачи данных в другие формы?

Comment: "В случае с массивами так сделать не получается." - это что значит?

Comment: создать отдельный класс только с массивами.. записывать их через вторую форму и читать всеми остальными

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958644/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-c

Comment: @Insider Ну,я его создаю. Обьявляю в нем массивы. А из формы-то их как менять? Формы массивы из класса не видят

Comment: сложно представить, что и как вы там создаете.. приведите код и обратите внимание на @Igor

Comment: А все формы у вас одновременно выведены на экран что-ли? Или все-таки сначала открываем форму ввода,  вводим данные, закрываем ее, а потом уже открываем 3-ю или 4-ю форму для просмотра введенных данных? Как нужно то?